# SASS add variable to list

Tags: css, sass

I've got the following variable list:

```
$list: 'one', 'two', 'three'
```

And I need to use this list, but with one more value, temporarily, how can I do something like this?

```
$list: 'one', 'two', 'three'
$list-group: $list, 'four'

@for $i from 1 through length($list-group)
    .color-#{ nth($list-group, $i) }
        content: nth($list-group, $i)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `insert-nth` or `append`

`append`:

```
append($list, 'four', [$separator])
```

`insert-nth`:

```
$list: 'one', 'two', 'three';
$list-group: insert-nth($list, 4, 'four');
```

Comment: insert-nth; is not an inbuilt method like append. so insert-nth does not work by itself, you need to provide a function to run this without error. Check out this article here this might help https://hugogiraudel.com/2013/08/08/advanced-sass-list-functions/